# Polymer. Ignoring 'resize' event by paper-dialog

Tags: polymer

I have `paper-dialog` element inside my custom element. I would like my paper-dialog element to ignore 'resize' event (when user resizes browser window), because my dialog is drag-and-droppable, and after 'resize' event fired - my dialog being refit.

I checked many native paper-dialog methods such as `stopResizeNotificationsFor(target)`, but they doesn't work as I expect.